# Unable to make WCF service call from a html file that has jQuery.ajax()

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery-ajax, wcf-rest

am trying to make  a  wcf service call from a .html file that has jQuery ajax() and stored in the site assets lib. i went to a page created a content editor web part and adde this .html file:

my service url :
`http://srvr1:2017/_layouts/15/SharePoint.WCFService.Sample/Services/SampleService.svc/GetDataJS()`
 this returns a string in my `operationcontract`.

here is my html code,but i am not able to make this work successfully.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/
     jquery-1.10.2.js"> 
  </script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {              
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            url: 'http://srvr1-
   02:2017/_layouts/15/SharePoint.WCFService.Sample/Services/SampleService.svc/GetD
 ataJS()',  
           success: function (data) {  
                $($.parseJSON(data.d)).each(function (index, value) {  
                    $("#TableID").append("<tr><td>" + value.ProductID+ "
      </td><td>" + value.ProductName+ "</td><td>" + value.ProductCategory + 
     "</td><td>" + value.Price + "</td>  </tr>");  
                });  
            },  
            error: function (result) {  
                alert(result);  
            }  
        });  
        });  
    // });  
  </script>
```

```
    <table id="TableID" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"  
    width="400px" >  
        <tr>  
            <td style="background-color: green; color:white">ProductID</td>  
            <td style="background-color: green; 
          color:white">ProductName</td>  
            <td style="background-color: green; 
       color:white">ProductCategory</td>  
            <td style="background-color: green; color:white">Price</td>  
        </tr>          </table>   </div>
```

when i access this svc url from a chrome  browser , its working fine , it emits the json data :
   `http://srvr1-02:2017/_layouts/15/SharePoint.WCFService.Sample/Services
    /SampleService.svc/GetDataJS()`

here is the snapshot of resultset when i access through chrome browser:
   [image: WORKING-JSON-RESULTSET]

[image: error-in-consuming-wcf]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) is the error , i am getting in the [F12] dev tools. and i updated the question with one more screen shot.